# Why was the method java.lang.Thread.join() named like that?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, naming

Does anybody know why the method join() member of a java.lang.Thread was named like that? Its javadoc is:

> Waits for this thread to die.

When join is called on some thread calling thread is waiting for the other to die and continue execution. Supposedly calling thread will die as well, but still it's not clear why the author used this name.

Comment: If you think join isn't exactly intuitive, read the German MSDN docs about System.Threading.Thread.Join(). It is translated as "verknüpfen", which means "link" rather than "join". Well, at least the docs say that it waits until the thread finished/ends (rather than die) ;)

Comment: Well, "verknüpfen" is "knot together". So I think they were trying to be helpful with their "thread" metaphor. Emphasis on *trying*.

Comment: Maybe. However, in software development terms, "verknüpfen" is always used for "link" (like in hyperlinks or shell links), so it's a rather bad choice. But there are many of those in the German translation of MSDN, though the major part of it is quite good. Sometimes it just seems that the translators didn't really know enough about the technical part. In older versions, "reference" was blindly translated as "Verweis", which is a reference in programming terms, but was also translated like this for reference documentation, where it doesn't make sense in German... But they fixed that one ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a common name in threading - it's not like Java was the first to use it. (For example, that's what [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining) uses too.)

I guess you could imagine it like two people taking a walk - you join the other one and walk with them until you've finished, before going back to what you were doing. That *sort* of analogy may have been the original reason, although I agree it's not exactly intuitive.

Answer (score 8):

It's named this way because you're basically stating that the calling thread of execution is going to wait to join the given state of execution. It's also named join in posix and many other threading packages.

After that call to join returns (unless it was interrupted), the two threads of execution are basically running together from that point (with that thread getting the return value of the now-terminated thread).

Comment: I would say better than "going to wait to join the given state of execution" the calling thread "joins the two threads together", so that there is then logically only one thread that does anything, instead of the two that were independent up to that point. Still not 100% satisfied with that expression though either.

Answer (score 6):

This stems from concurrent software modeling when the flow of control splits into to concurrent threads. Later, the two threads of execution will join again.

Also `waitToDie()` was probably a) too long and b) too morbid.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense now. `wait()` could also have been an option though...

Comment: This must be the real rationale behind the nomenclature

Answer (score 2):

well... this isnt really correct but I thought of an "waiting room" (it actually isnt a queue with a certain scheduling as FIFO, HRRN or such).
when a thread cannot go on and needs to wait on some other thread to finish it just joins the guys (aka threads) in the waiting room to get active next...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are waiting for another thread of execution (i.e. the one you're calling join on) to join (i.e. die) to the current (i.e. the calling) thread.

The calling thread does not die: it simply waits for the other thread to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terminology that is widely used(outside Java as well). I take it as sort of Associating a Thread with another one in some way. I think Thread.Associate() could have been a better option but Join() isn't bad either.

Comment: To me, Thread.associate() would imply some kind of connection between the two threads beyond the call, but as separate entities. I think that's misleading as the given thread is no longer running, but rather combining into a single execution path as defined by the call to join().